# Jupyter Notebook Not Showing Output

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-console

I have using jupyter notebook for past few months. I am facing this type of problem for the first time.

**Exact Problem : When I run a cell on jupyter notebook it is running for long time, but not showing any output.**

**Solution that I have already tried based on some google searches:**
1. Uninstalled anaconda and reinstalled it.
2. Updated conda
3. Updated ipykernel
4. Download and installed microsoft visual c++ 2015 redistribute update 3
5. Restarted kernel and tried again
6. Shutdown files in running tab
7. And so on.

**Properties:**
1. Windows 10 Pro
2. Python : Python 3.6.7
3. Jupyter :-
jupyter core     : 4.6.3
jupyter-notebook : 6.1.1
qtconsole        : 4.7.5
ipython          : 7.16.1
ipykernel        : 5.3.4
jupyter client   : 6.1.6
jupyter lab      : not installed
nbconvert        : 5.6.1
ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
nbformat         : 5.0.7
traitlets        : 4.3.3
4. Anaconda 3 - 64 bit

**Error showing in jupyter notebook prompt:**

```
[I 21:24:04.349 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\Users\Mathesh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 21:24:04.349 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Users\Mathesh\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 21:24:04.411 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\Mathesh
[I 21:24:04.411 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 21:24:04.418 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=8e7be14b316ad1fd7bfb00fe144e3a98ea7655979b6d18dd
[I 21:24:04.418 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 21:24:04.555 NotebookApp]

Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
to login with a token:
    http://localhost:8888/?token=8e7be14b316ad1fd7bfb00fe144e3a98ea7655979b6d18dd
[I 21:24:15.956 NotebookApp] Accepting one-time-token-authenticated connection from ::1
[I 21:24:47.204 NotebookApp] Kernel started: f321d571-c5dc-41c0-867e-6e69da753793
[I 21:25:07.344 NotebookApp] Starting buffering for f321d571-c5dc-41c0-867e-6e69da753793:2828c21d9fb2439fb9aa4251d66f845a
[I 21:25:08.333 NotebookApp] Restoring connection for f321d571-c5dc-41c0-867e-6e69da753793:2828c21d9fb2439fb9aa4251d66f845a
[W 21:26:38.362 NotebookApp] WebSocket ping timeout after 90013 ms.
[I 21:26:43.385 NotebookApp] Starting buffering for f321d571-c5dc-41c0-867e-6e69da753793:2828c21d9fb2439fb9aa4251d66f845a
[I 21:26:44.458 NotebookApp] Restoring connection for f321d571-c5dc-41c0-867e-6e69da753793:2828c21d9fb2439fb9aa4251d66f845a
[I 21:26:45.506 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Desktop/Testing_Sample.ipynb
[I 21:27:35.723 NotebookApp] Kernel restarted: f321d571-c5dc-41c0-867e-6e69da753793
[I 21:27:45.719 NotebookApp] Starting buffering for f321d571-c5dc-41c0-867e-6e69da753793:2828c21d9fb2439fb9aa4251d66f845a
[I 21:27:45.860 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Desktop/Testing_Sample.ipynb
[I 21:27:53.886 NotebookApp] Kernel shutdown: f321d571-c5dc-41c0-867e-6e69da753793
[W 21:27:53.891 NotebookApp] 404 POST /api/kernels/f321d571-c5dc-41c0-867e-6e69da753793/restart (::1): Kernel does not exist: f321d571-c5dc-41c0-867e-6e69da753793
[W 21:27:53.892 NotebookApp] Kernel does not exist: f321d571-c5dc-41c0-867e-6e69da753793
[W 21:27:53.892 NotebookApp] 404 POST /api/kernels/f321d571-c5dc-41c0-867e-6e69da753793/restart (::1) 19414.84ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Desktop/Testing_Sample.ipynb
```

**Sample image for Reference:**
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aITxCLfK1NViosRCdE6iORTHtO9sDgYX/view?usp=sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buhXZ.png)

Since I am new user I am unable to post an image. So I have attached the drive link of that image.

Advance thanks for sparing time on my question.

Comment: What do you mean by it is long running?? Can you post the Code running in that Cell??

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I have attached a sample image for your reference as a drive link. You view it in my post in "sample image for reference" section.